# How can I change the effective (not actual) screen resolution in X11?

Tags: x11, screen-resolution, xorg

I want to occasionally VNC from an old laptop to my main PC. The old laptop's screen resolution (1024x768) is much lower than the PC's resolution (which at the moment is 1280x1024).

A few months ago, I set up x11vnc on my PC so that it would automatically lower the screen resolution when I connected and restore the optimum resolution when I was done. This worked incredibly well (seriously, it was awesome)... until I noticed that the backlight in the LCD attached to the PC seemed to be having issues.

Turns out, all the (very very frequent) screen resolution changes were killing the backlight lifespan, because (like most LCDs) the backlight on this LCD switches off and back on whenever the resolution changes.

Once I realized this I immediately stopped VNCing, which was extremely inconvenient and a major workflow disruption. However I couldn't risk killing my LCD.

So, **I am looking for a way to lower the resolution in X11 in a way that does not cause the backlight to flicker**.

In other words, **I want to change the resolution X11 reports to programs without adjusting the actual screen resolution.**

I've already been lowering and restoring the screen resolution for some time, so I am used to windows getting thrown around a bit.

And I fully expect that when the "effective" resolution is lowered, all the windows will probably bunch toward the top-right with a giant empty black area covering a lot of the screen. This is also fine.

I'm aware Openbox has a "margins" system that will affect the state of maximized windows, but I'm not using Openbox. (I'm currently using i3 but this is likely to change in future.)

Ideally I want the solution to be windowmanager-independent. Something that sits between X11 and the WM, ideally. Writing a program that watches floating windows and automatically moves them within a constrained area would be trivial to write - it's adjusting the state of *maximized* windows I'm stumped on!

I realize this is a particularly tricky question, and appreciate any ideas and suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure you want to engage in such dirty hacks? You can scale, you can pan, and you can connect to a virtual X session (not on your physical desktop) which you should be doing regardless anyway.